# Quickblox WebRTC iOS: Receiver connection closes, unable to accept the call

Tags: ios, quickblox

Rewriting my iOS app to use the new WebRTC SDK for video call and facing this issue when in the call receiver side. When the caller starts the call, the session is received in the receiver but when the call is accepted (session:acceptCall), the connection just closes like this. **-session:connectionFailedWithUser** is called at the end.

```
 (Log at the call receiver side)

      2015-06-05 16:15:43.038 [2846:195100] Renegotiation needed. userID - 3027703

      2015-06-05 16:15:43.275 [2846:195100] Error(-1): Error Domain=RTCSDPError Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (RTCSDPError error -1.)" 

      UserInfo=0x1729d6a0 {error=SessionDescription is NULL.}

      2015-06-05 16:15:43.353 [2846:195100] Ice Gathering change: Complete, userID - 3027703

      2015-06-05 16:15:43.355 [2846:195100] Signaling state change: Closed, userID - 3027703
```

Am I missing something or is this an issue with the SDK? The sample with the same version of the SDK works, but it doesn't in my app. The only thing that's different is the Quickblox account key and secret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was with the SDK and doesn't occur anymore in the latest SDKs. 
Please use Quickblox SDK versioned 2.3.0.1 and Quickblox WebRTC SDK 1.0.6.